# openmp nested parallelism and num_threads(1)

Tags: c++, openmp

So I just, after an inappropriate amount of time, found out, that even if you have nested OpenMP disabled, the inner parallel region in the following sample will still run in parallel:

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(1)
{
    printf("BBB thread %d/%d level %d %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_num_threads(), omp_get_active_level(), omp_get_level());

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        printf("CCC thread %d/%d level %d %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_num_threads(), omp_get_active_level(), omp_get_level());
    }
}
```

Yes, I did set `num_threads` to 1, but it still is a parallel region. Why does it not behave as one in terms of nested OpenMP? Why is (an equivalent of) `omp_get_active_level()` used to determine the nest-ism, instead of `omp_get_level()`? It just does not make sense to me. Why `num_threads(3)` behaves analogously to `num_threads(2)`, but `num_threads(1)` behaves differently?

Is this behavior expected? I tested with g++ and icpx compilers and both work in the same way.

`if(false)` has the same effect as `num_threads(1)`, but that's is expectable, since with this you actually specify that you don't want to launch a parallel region. But it still affects `omp_get_level()`, which seems weird.

I did read [this algorithm](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu35.html#x55-880002.6.1), so this is more of a question of why is it designed in such a way?

btw this is the output I am getting, when `OMP_NUM_THREADS=4` (AAA is completely outside any parallel region):

```
AAA thread 0/1 level 0 0

num_threads(3):
BBB thread 1/3 level 1 1
CCC thread 0/1 level 1 2
BBB thread 0/3 level 1 1
CCC thread 0/1 level 1 2
BBB thread 2/3 level 1 1
CCC thread 0/1 level 1 2

num_threads(2):
BBB thread 1/2 level 1 1
CCC thread 0/1 level 1 2
BBB thread 0/2 level 1 1
CCC thread 0/1 level 1 2

num_threads(1):
BBB thread 0/1 level 0 1
CCC thread 0/4 level 1 2
CCC thread 1/4 level 1 2
CCC thread 2/4 level 1 2
CCC thread 3/4 level 1 2
```

and the full program:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <omp.h>

int main()
{
    printf("AAA thread %d/%d level %d %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_num_threads(), omp_get_active_level(), omp_get_level());

    printf("\nnum_threads(3):\n");
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(3)
    {
        printf("BBB thread %d/%d level %d %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_num_threads(), omp_get_active_level(), omp_get_level());

        #pragma omp parallel
        {
            printf("CCC thread %d/%d level %d %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_num_threads(), omp_get_active_level(), omp_get_level());
        }
    }

    printf("\nnum_threads(2):\n");
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
    {
        printf("BBB thread %d/%d level %d %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_num_threads(), omp_get_active_level(), omp_get_level());

        #pragma omp parallel
        {
            printf("CCC thread %d/%d level %d %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_num_threads(), omp_get_active_level(), omp_get_level());
        }
    }

    printf("\nnum_threads(1):\n");
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(1)
    {
        printf("BBB thread %d/%d level %d %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_num_threads(), omp_get_active_level(), omp_get_level());

        #pragma omp parallel
        {
            printf("CCC thread %d/%d level %d %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_num_threads(), omp_get_active_level(), omp_get_level());
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you can, I strongly advise you not to use nesting. In many cases, tasks should be used instead nowadays. They are more flexible, cause less issues and can even help to increase performance in some cases, though they can also make things slower in some other cases (especially on NUMA systems or when the granularity of the tasks is too small).

Comment: Also please note that using `num_threads(3)` is generally considered as a bad idea (due to the lack of flexibility) unless your application requires the exact number of threads to be generated (generally no: this is dependent of the target platform). `OMP_NUM_THREADS` can be used to configure that by end-users.

Comment: What exactly is your point? Do you have a code where the current behavior hurts? Seems to me like most people would rather have the nesting work in instances like this. For example if the `num_threads` is determined at runtime as `min(num_items_outer_loop, omp_get_max_threads())` with some outer loop having potentially just one entry but an inner loop allowing more parallelization as a fallback. Adding an extra `if` clause seems redundant

Comment: Your assumption is wrong, you have never disabled nested parallelism. Using `num_threads(1)` clause does not disable nested parallelism, it also does not prevent  creating a parallel region. It does create a parallel region with 1 thread (but it is considered inactive). So `omp_get_active_level()` returns 0, while `omp_get_level()` return 1, because it considers inactive parallel regions as well.

Comment: So, I believe the results you obtained align with expectations based on the OpenMP specification. If you're seeing different numbers when using omp_get_active_level() compared to omp_get_level(), it indicates that your compiler has optimized your code and executed a parallel region using only one thread (i.e inactive parallel region). While `omp_get_level()` returns the "theoretical" level of nested parallelism, `omp_get_active_level()` returns the actual level after compiler optimizations (e.i. not considering inactive parallel regions).

Comment: @JérômeRichard I would like to not use nesting, but I am working with a library that uses OpenMP on the inside and I cannot change it, but for my use case it is useless and I want to use OpenMP on the outside. This is not any near to production code, just a demonstration to show the problem, I know the best practices.

Comment: @Homer512 I do, and it does hurt in my use case, as parallelization on the inside slows down the program ~4x due to really small work size. So I want to parallelize on the outside. I wanted the program to use N cores by setting num_threads(N), then do some tests (really I am using only N=1 or N=omp_get_max_threads()). But for N=1 this does not work, as parallelization kicks in on the inside.

Comment: @Laci I did not disable nested parallelism, because it is disabled by default. I did also try setting `OMP_MAX_ACTIVE_LEVELS=1`, but that did not change anything. I do understand now the difference between active/inactive parallel regios, but I don't understand the reason why nest-ism is based only on the active regions, not the inactive ones.

Comment: My understanding is that the main problem with nesting is the oversubscription of resources which does not happen if the outer region is inactive. There you have a reason. I think your gripes should rather be with any library that does not have a way of compiling it without OMP or at least checks if there is enough work for OMP to make sense at runtime. Seems like that library just doesn't cover your use-case.

Comment: Shouldn't `OMP_NUM_THREADS=1,1` make sure that both levels are inactive for your test? See the [docs](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpse50.html)

Comment: @paleonix Yes it will, but it affects the whole application, but I just need the one part to be sequential. But using e.g. `OMP_NUM_THREADS=4,1` does resolve the issue for me, the inner parallel region will always be sequential. Thanks for the suggestion.

Anyway, it's strange that `OMP_NUM_THREADS=4,1,1,1,1`... is *not* equivalent to disabling nested parallelism.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling nesting is equivalent to setting *max-active-levels-var* to 1 - either using the environmental variable (`OMP_MAX_ACTIVE_LEVELS=1`) or using the runtime function (`omp_set_max_active_levels(1)`). A parallel region executing with a single thread is defined as inactive parallel region. Therefore such parallel region does not count towards the max active regions limit.
As other comments suggested, the `num_threads` clause should only be used when really necessary. The more flexible way is to export `OMP_NUM_THREADS=1,4` to get the output for your last experiement.